# Cannot connect to named instance of SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, connection, sql-server-2008-r2, database-project

I am attempting to create a new Database Project in VS2010 via the New Project Wizard, and via this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833432(v=vs.100).aspx

I am on the 'Configure Build/Deploy' step, and am attempting to connect to a named instance of SQL Server 2008R2 that I just installed, called DEVELOPMENT. Assuming the server name is DB-01, I am using DB-01\DEVELOPMENT as the Server name in the dialog in the screenshot below. I'm also using the remaining settings in the dialog, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to the SQL Server. The server was not found
>   or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.)

DEV is the name of a database I created on the DEVELOPMENT instance. If I use DB-01 as the server name, which is the default instance, it connects. In the past, we've been developing from a database on the default instance, with no issues, but I'm trying to move to local, source-controlled databases. What am I missing with this not connecting?

EDIT: As a little more context, it's not the username/pw combination, or the existence of the DEV db on the instance, because I receive different errors if either of those are incorrect. It's simply not able to connect once I give it the named instance.

[image]

Comment: Are trying to connect remotely or locally?

Comment: The mysql connection port is 1433 by default. Try to run the following command 
              telnet ipserver 1433.
With this you can see if the port is open or if you have problems with the firewall

Comment: Yes, that connects with no issue, which makes sense because the default, unnamed instance (DB-01) connects with no issue, and it also uses port 1433.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

The default instance of SQL Server (called MSSQLSERVER in some places) uses port 1433 by default for incoming connections, which was opened in Windows Firewall. This is why I was able to connect to the default instance (DB-01). If you've created a named instance of SQL Server, by default these instances use port 1434 for incoming connections. These are TCP ports for each case. Well, I have to admit that I opened TCP port 1434 in Windows Firewall and still was not able to connect to the named instance remotely, and still am not sure why this was the case. So instead, I opened up a random port (6969) in Windows Firewall, and configured the DEVELOPMENT (named) instance to accept incoming connecting over that port only. For instructions on how to configure specific SQL Server instances to use ports other than the default, see this article:

[Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)

Once I configured the instance to use port 6969, I was able to connect with no issue. Hope this helps others that are having a similar/same issue.